# Django template for loop , new page for each 15 items

Tags: python, django

Now I'm working in a billing app. I have a custom designed billing page. that page can include 15 products. if I print more than 15 products , thats will override into their footer. so, If more than 15 products , then create a new page for every 15 items. how can I do this.

My View

```
@login_required    
def print_sale(request,uuid):
    current_sale = Sales.objects.filter(uuid=uuid,deleted=0,shop_id = get_current_shop_id(request)).annotate(total=Sum('sale_products__subtotal'),total_received=Sum('sale_payment__amount'))
    return render_to_response('sales/print.html',{'current_sale':current_sale},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />        
        <title>print</title>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/print.css' %}" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/print.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="wrapper">
            {%if current_sale %}
                {% for sale in current_sale %}
                    <section id="top">
                        <section id="bill_details" class="style1">
                            <h2>Bill To :</h2>
                            <p>
                                {{ sale.customer.name }} , {{ sale.customer.email }} , {{sale.customer.mobile}}
                            </p>
                            <p class="address">
                                {{ sale.customer.address }}
                            </p>
                        </section>
                        <div class="right">
                            <p>
                                <b>Date <small>:</small></b>{{ sale.sale_date }}
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <b>Invoice No<small>:</small></b> #{{ sale.id }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <br class="clear" />
                    </section>              
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                        {% for product in sale.sale_products_set.all  %}
                        <tr class="parent">
                            <td>{{ product.product.code }}</td>
                            <td>{{ product.product.name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/.

Answer (score 1):

Django provides support for [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/)

However, The easiest way would be to use [django-pagination](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination) app.

Once you set it up, here is what you need to include in the template:

```
{# At the top of the template #}
{% load pagination_tags %}
{% autopaginate sale.sale_products_set.all 15 %}

{# Your normal template code here #}

{# At the bottom, to show the pagination buttons #}
{% paginate %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some better to implement pagination with some better experience you can have a look into [django endless pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org) 
Django Endless Pagination can be used to provide Twitter-style or Digg-style pagination, with optional Ajax support and other features like multiple or lazy pagination.